# How to call saved dataItem in Android Wear?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I'm creating a watchface that can have the color customized through an App that is on the phone.

I've seen examples use the `DataApi` and `DataItem` to save/load settings.

The problem I am encountering is that when I change to a different watchface and change back, all the values inside the `DataMap` seems to be reset to null or 0.

Here is a sample of my `onCreate()` method of the Wear watchface, which will try to load the last used color:

```
    PendingResult<DataItemBuffer> results = Wearable.DataApi.getDataItems(mGoogleApiClient);
    results.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataItemBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DataItemBuffer dataItems) {
        if (dataItems.getCount() != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataItems.getCount(); i++) {
                DataMapItem dataMapItem = DataMapIfromDataItem(dataItems.get(i));
                if (dataMapItem.getDataMap().containsKey(COLOR_KEY)) {
                    mSelectedColor = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getInt(COLOR_PATH);
                    }
                }
            }
            dataItems.release();
        }
    });
```

Note that the `mSelectedColor = dataMap...` line will return 0.

Here is the code sample from the mobile app that will store this data:

```
        PutDataMapRequest dataMap = PutDataMapRequest.create(COLOR_PATH);
        dataMap.getDataMap().putInt(COLOR_KEY, mSelectedColor);
```

Sending/retreiving the color value works while running, and `onDestroy()` or `onStop()` aren't modifying the data back to 0.

Are dataItems automatically "disposed" when an activity/watchface is closed, or am I implementing this thing wrong?

Thanks for the helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've got the wrong constant on your `getInt` call. `COLOR_PATH` is the URI path, `COLOR_KEY` is the key of the `int` you're trying to retrieve. You should have:

```
mSelectedColor = dataMapItem.getDataMap().getInt(COLOR_KEY);
```

Comment: Oh man... can't believe I made such an obvious mistake :/
Thank you so much!